# a ntservice c++ program can work well in xp but error in windows7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp

i wrote a program in c++ of win32, unicode; it uses socket to read data from another program;
i tested it in a local pc; i compiled it with vs2008;

when used as a console mode, it works properly in both winxp and win7; 
when used as a ntservice, it works in xp, but fails in windows7;

in win7, that is, its socket is work well, and it can output logs used logcplus, but it can not access another program's api to read data; meanwhile, its logs cannot show in debugview, though i output logs used OutputDebugString under debug mode;

---

http://technet.microsoft.com/zh-cn/query/bb203962(v=VS.71) says:
Session 0 Isolation
 Services have always run in session 0. Before Windows Vista, the first user to log on was also assigned to session 0. Now, session 0 is reserved exclusively for services and other applications not associated with an interactive user session. (The first user to log on is connected to session 1, the second user to log on is connected to session 2, and so on.) Session 0 does not support processes that interact with the user.

**This change means that a service cannot post or send a message to an application and an application cannot send or post a message to a service**. In addition, services cannot display a user interface item such as a dialog box directly. A service can use the WTSSendMessage function to display a dialog box in another session.

if it is the reason, how to resolve it?
thanks

Comment: What does it mean "but it can not access another program's api to read data"?

Comment: Session isolation is not relevant to sockets, WTSSendMessage is only relevant to Windows messages.  You are on the wrong track, not documenting the "error" prevents any kind of sane answer.